# wrong URL parsed using jQuery Load()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine

I have to post a data from a page using jquery.load().
I put it on a page with spark viewengine. the post method fire where a button click, will execute a js function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayCheckedOrders() {        
        var $checkedRecords = $(':checked');

        if ($checkedRecords.length < 1) {
            alert('Check a few grid rows first.');
            return;
        }
        var url = '${Url.Action("myaction","Account")}';
        var temp = $('#xresult').load(url, $checkedRecords);
    }
</script>
```

but, it didn't parse a correct url,

[image]

any solution for my problem ?

Comment: hmm, I think it was because I put the javascript in a single js file, so spark view engine can't render the helper (${Url.Action..blablabal..)

when I move script to spark file, it's works :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - view engine will process the view file to create your url - if you put it in external js then url will be taken as is. A simple solution is to move the relevant js function to the view file. Yet another alternative is to parameterize your external js function to accept the url (as parameter) and construct actual value in the view file.